# Bases associated with a given Euclidean Structure

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This comes from a homework question: For $\bf x, \bf y$ $\in \mathbb{R}^n$, put $\langle {\bf x}, {\bf x} \rangle$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n 2x_i^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_ix_{i+1}$. Show that the corresponding symmetric bilinear form defines on $\mathbb{R}^n$ a Euclidean structure.

A few questions about this, mostly definitions.

First, I see that, on any vector space $\mathcal{V}$, with ${\bf x} \in \mathcal{V}$, a given formula for an inner product $\langle {\bf x},{\bf x} \rangle = Q({\bf x})$ defines a quadratic form, which corresponds to a symmetric bilinear form $B({\bf x}, {\bf y})$. My first question is: Is the matrix of the mapping $Q: \mathcal{V} \to \mathbb{R}$ ALWAYS the same as the matrix of the mapping $B: \mathcal{V} \times \mathcal{V} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Now, there is a fundamental theorem of linear algebra that any real finite dimensional vector space $\mathcal{V}$ is isomorphic to the standard coordinate space $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n = \dim(\mathcal{V})$. My second question is: Are all inner products for $\mathcal{V}$ typically given in $\mathbb{R}^n$? i.e do mathematicians always think of any space $\mathcal{V}$ as its isomorphic equivalent $\mathbb{R}^n$? It seems that way.

In the inner product given in my homework problem, a quadratic form is given that we are to check and see if we can use it as a Euclidean structure (Euclidean inner product) on $\mathbb{R}^n$. In this formula we are given $x_i$'s, components of a vector $\bf x$ on SOME BASIS. My third and main question is: Am I to assume that these $x_i$'s are components with respect to the standard orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\{{\bf e}_i\}$? Or are they in fact relative to some unknown basis $\{{\bf f}_i\}$, not necessarily orthonormal? If it is with respect to $\{{\bf f}_i\}$, can we find a formula for these vectors in terms of $\{{\bf e}_i\}$?

For example, when we are given $\langle {\bf x}, {\bf x} \rangle$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$, it is clear to me that we are in the standard orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Fourth question: What is this inner product called? It must be given a special name since we use it so often.

Thanks for helping to clear up all the subtleties!

Edit: I should add that the second part of the question is: Find the angles between the standard coordinate axes in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The answer in the back of the book is: $\theta({\bf e}_i , {\bf e}_{i+1}) = \frac{2 \pi}{3}$, while all other pairs are perpendicular. Huh? I thought the standard coordinate axes for $\mathbb{R}^n$ were ALWAYS orthogonal??

Answer (score 1):

A lot of good questions here.

First, every symmetric bilinear form $B(\mathbf x, \mathbf y)$ can be expressed in terms of the Euclidean scalar product as $(\mathbf y, A\mathbf x)$, where $A$ is a linear transformation. The related quadratic form is then $Q(\mathbf x)=B(\mathbf x,\mathbf x)=(\mathbf x,A\mathbf x)$, so, yes, the matrices are the same.

For your second point, mathematicians don’t always think of a vector space as $\mathbb R^n$, but it is a convenient and familiar model for reasoning about the more abstract space, so you’ll see it a lot.

Third: I thinks it’s safe to assume that the formula for the scalar product is given in terms of the standard basis, especially when a later part of the the problem talks about finding the angles between those basis vectors. You make a good point though: for it to be well-defined, its value shouldn’t depend on choice of basis. The *matrix* associated with a scalar product, on the other hand, of course depends on the choice of basis.

If I understand your fourth question correctly, the name of this “standard” scalar product is the *Euclidean scalar (or inner) product* aka *dot product*. When someone talks about the “inner product” with no other context, they usually mean this one.

Finally, orthogonality is defined relative to some inner product. The standard basis vectors are mutually orthogonal w/r the Euclidean scalar product, but may not be relative to others. It looks to me like they want you to calculate $\langle\mathbf e_i,\mathbf e_j\rangle$ and then use the interpretation of an inner product as $\|\mathbf x\|\|\mathbf y\|\cos\theta$ to determine the angle.